# Can I combine a list of similar dataframes into a single dataframe?

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
foo <- list(df1 = data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'),y = c(1,2,3)), 
            df2 = data.frame(x=c('d', 'e', 'f'),y = c(4,5,6)))
```

Can I convert it to a single dataframe of the form:

```
data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), y= c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748537/merging-several-data-frames-into-a-single-expanded-frame and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392915/recombining-a-list-of-data-frames-into-a-single-data-frame and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/r-converting-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame ... Please do a search before you ask a question: If I can remember at least 2 questions with appx the same title, you didn't do any effort, did you?

Comment: @Joris, thanks for pointing those out, but your memory functions better than my queries + the SO search engine: none of these answers showed up in the 89 results for "[r] +list +dataframe" or the first 100 records of my searches, including "[r] convert list to dataframe" and "[r] combine list to dataframe". I would appreciate suggestions for searches that would have found these results.

Comment: with [r] combine data frame you get at least one of the related questions on the first page. With [r] combine list data frame you get it as a second answer. I agree that when you write dataframe as one word, it gets tricky. Sorry for the harsh tone of my earlier comment.

Comment: on a sidenote: it's better to keep these words seperate, as quite some people write them as data-frame (recognized as 2 words by the search engine).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`do.call("rbind", foo)` should do the trick.

Comment: A much more efficient solution is `rbindlist` from data.table. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind) for details and benchmarking.

Comment: `rbind_list` is now deprecated and you should use `dplyr::bind_rows` instead.

Answer (score 7):

with `plyr`:

```
foo <- list(df1 = data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'),y = c(1,2,3)), 
        df2 = data.frame(x=c('d', 'e', 'f'),y = c(4,5,6)))

library(plyr)
ldply(foo)[,-1]
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
4 d 4
5 e 5
6 f 6
```

Comment: Also `rbind.fill` in `plyr`, which works like `do.call("rbind", list)`, but allows mismatched column names.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code.

The first is that the assignment statement in the list doesn't work.  This needs to be fixed by, for example:

```
foo <- list(
        df1 = data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'), y = c(1,2,3)), 
        df2 = data.frame(x=c('d', 'e', 'f'), y = c(4,5,6))
)
```

You can then use rbind() to combine the data frames:

```
rbind(foo$df1, foo$df2)

  x y
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
4 d 4
5 e 5
6 f 6
```

But this poses more questions.  For example, why do you combine the data frames in a list in the first place.  The second is whether you really need to use data frames rather than vectors.  Finally, I generally try to avoid rbind() and rather use merge() when combining data frames in this way.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error in my code. I have fixed it. Thanks also for your answer - i didn't realize that it was so simple. The actual data frames are much bigger, and my workflow makes frequent use of lapply, here I just want to bind the dataframes so that `xtable` will mae a single table.,

Comment: @David, that makes complete sense now.  If you often use lapply, you may also wish to have a look at the functions in plyr, which provide a general framework for this type of problem.  Then the solution simply becomes ldply(foo, rbind)

Answer (score 1):

How about `merge(foo[[1]], foo[[2]], all = TRUE)`